# Unable to connect domain name to server

Tags: domain

I am trying to connect mydomainname.com to my server running centos minimal 7.  I am relatively new at this so from what i know I did the following.

DNS management for mydomainname.com

Name (www)       Type (CNAME)    TTL (14440)        Target  (mydomainname.com)

On my Centos 7 server 
My **hosts** file reads
ip address of server  mydomainname.com

When i try to go to mydomainname.com i get the error message "Unable to connect".

Comment: Are you able to ping the remote host using mydomainname.com?

Comment: yes I am able to ping it.

Comment: mydomainname.com does not have an address record, but www.mydomainname.com does have a CNAME record (that points elsewhere than you state in your question). You cannot access mydomainname.com until you fix this.

Comment: I added the following:  
Name (www) Type (A)  TTL (14440)  Target (server ip address).  I still get the same error.

Comment: This question is going to be a *lot* easier to answer if you tell us the domain name.  Failing that, at least please **redact properly**.  See [this meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your iptables is allowing incoming connections on port 80.

Comment: it's open.  I have used this server before for another website I had and it worked fine.  That is why i am so lost, all i did was put in a new site in the html folder.

Comment: i am thinking it might have something to do with nameserver.  The new domain i registered has their default nameserver.  I don't know much about namesever, do I need to change this value to something else?

Comment: If you telnet the external domain on port 80, does it work? Or does it give you a time-out.

Comment: A nameserver translates a domain name to an IP-adress, every provider uses its own DNS nameservers, thats OK!

Comment: that might be the problem, telnet says connection refused.  I ran nmap command and it says port 80 is open.

Comment: I think it means that it is listening to incoming connections, i dont think it means that your port is open to the outside. If telnet doesnt work, it tells you that the connection is being blocked. Maybe your router is the problem?

Comment: this is running on a vps server with static ip address.  I updated my comment, running the nmap command says port 80 /tcp is open.  You are right, but what could be blocking it, the port looks like it's open.

Comment: Just for fun, can you disable iptables on the centos machine? If nmap tells you the port is open, it must be an internal firewall.

Comment: disabled iptables, connection still refused by telnet and unable to go to domainname.com

Comment: Whats your domain name? See comment MadHatter

Comment: I did a quick check with telnet and nmap, both applications report that port 80 is blocked. This is all i can tell you ...

Comment: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/